# Embed quicksight through Java sdk

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

to give a brief about my situation:
Earlier I was using chart.js for creating charts in my dashboard. Then I came across Quicksight a couple of days back. So I thought of switching to it as it provides better handling without any hassle.

Before Quicksight I was using jsp for my page, js(jquery) for my frontend and Java as my backend (spring-boot) with MongoDB as my database.

Keeping my structure same I just defined a jsp so that the user can be directed to the particular page after hitting on the chats.
Then, in my js file, I have written a (my own defined) ajaxRequest that will direct it to the Java controller:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    ajaxRequest("/myService/char/getQuickSight", "GET", "", function(response){
    })
}
```

);

Now I am not able to understand how to go on with my controller class. I have written something like this:

```
private static AmazonQuickSight getClient() {

        final AWSCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                // provide actual IAM access key and secret key here
                return new BasicAWSCredentials("access-key", "secret-key");
            }

            @Override
            public void refresh() {
            }
        };

        return AmazonQuickSightClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1.getName())
                .withCredentials(credsProvider).build();
}
```

For he above code I refered to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-example-java.html)

It is also throughing an error:

> ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;] with root cause
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;

(I can also provide the full stacktrace..)

But I am not able to understand how to move forward and what to do with the code. So if anyone can help me out I'll really appreciate it.

P.S. I have also added the following dependency in my POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-quicksight</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.457</version>
    </dependency>
```